# Tensorflow How to Train 2 CNN(independent) on 2 GPUs. CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY Error

Tags: tensorflow, multi-gpu

1 PC with 2 GPUs. To train 2 independent CNNs on 2 GPUs. I use followings to create graph for GPU:

```
  with tf.device('/gpu:%d' % self.single_gpu):
    self._create_placeholders()
    self._build_conv_net()
    self._create_cost()
    self._creat_optimizer()
```

Training loop is not under th.device()

After starting 1st CNN training process, such as using GPU 1. Then, I start 2nd CNN training with GPU 0. I always get CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY error, and could not start 2nd training process.

Running 2 independent training tasks assigned to 2 GPUs on same PC possible? If possible, what am I missing?

```
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:1002] failed to allocate 164.06M (172032000 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
```

W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:274] *******____******************_______________________________________________________________________
    W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:275] Ran out of memory trying to allocate 384.00MiB.  See logs for memory state.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/hl/anaconda3/envs/dl-conda-py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1022, in _do_call
        return fn(*args)
      File "/home/hl/anaconda3/envs/dl-conda-py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1004, in _run_fn
        status, run_metadata)
      File "/home/hl/anaconda3/envs/dl-conda-py36/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 89, in **exit**
        next(self.gen)
      File "/home/hl/anaconda3/envs/dl-conda-py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
        pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
    tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Dst tensor is not initialized.
         [[Node: _recv_inputs/input_placeholder_0/_7 = _Recvclient_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:2", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_3__recv_inputs/input_placeholder_0", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:2"]]
         [[Node: Mean/_15 = _Recvclient_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:2", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_414_Mean", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mg_model_nvidia_gpu.py", line 491, in <module>
    main()
  File "mg_model_nvidia_gpu.py", line 482, in main
    nvidia_cnn.train(data_generator, train_data, val_data)
  File "mg_model_nvidia_gpu.py", line 307, in train
    self.keep_prob: self.train_config.keep_prob})
  File "/home/hl/anaconda3/envs/dl-conda-py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 767, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/hl/anaconda3/envs/dl-conda-py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 965, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/hl/anaconda3/envs/dl-conda-py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1015, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/hl/anaconda3/envs/dl-conda-py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1035, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Dst tensor is not initialized.
     [[Node: _recv_inputs/input_placeholder_0/_7 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:2", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_3__recv_inputs/input_placeholder_0", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:2"]()]]
     [[Node: Mean/_15 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:2", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_414_Mean", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, TensorFlow pre-allocates the whole memory of the GPU devices it has access to. Therefore no memory is available for the second process.

You can control this allocation using the `config.gpu_options`:

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.4
sess = tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
```

or you could attribute to your two processes a different card by using the `os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]`.

Comment: Therefore, process 1 to use gpu 0:
 os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"]="PCI_BUS_ID"
 os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0" 

 tf.device('/gpu:0'):

process 2 to use gpu 3:
 os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"]="PCI_BUS_ID"
 os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="3" 

 tf.device('/gpu:3'):

are needed to use 2 gpu?

Comment: How about 1 training process, 2 tasks to parallel batch data into 2 GPUs? Same configuration as above or not?

Comment: I think in this case you would need to use tensorflow distributed so the training process and the 2 tasks talk to each others.

Comment: os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0,3" is for 1 process to be able to use GPU 0 and 3? And then, tf.device() can be used to assign task 1 to gpu 0 and task 2 to use gpu 3? I will have to experiment. This configuration is really confusing. Without os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0,3", 2nd process report CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY.